# Regex (python) capturing a parameter positive lookahead

Tags: python, regex

Been trying to figure this out for awhile, not getting much success. I was wondering if someone could help.

I have a series of potential strings, below are the sources. Basically, I'm trying to retrieve a certain value from a parameter (let's say `my_param`); but it could be at either the beginning of the `string`, the middle of the `string`, or the end of the `string`.

How can I generate a `python` `regex` to capture this for all the scenarios?

This is what I have so far: `((&_csrf)|(_csrf))=(.*)(?=&)`

The issue is that if it's at the end of the `string` it returns no matches or if there are multiple `parameters` then it lumps in the next `parameter`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Source String 1:

```
my_param=stuffinhereIwant&some_other_param=Idontcareaboutthis&some_param2=Don'tWantThisEither
```

Source string 2:

```
some_param=Idontcareaboutthis&my_param=stuffinhereIwant&some_param2=Don'tWantThisEither
```

Source string 3:

```
some_param=Idontcareaboutthis&some_param2=Don'tWantThisEither&my_param=stuffinhereIwant
```

Source string 4:

```
my_param=stuffhereIwant
```

Comment: Is your string always prepended by `my_param=`? If not, clarify your matching rule better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query strings are best handled with the parse_qs function.

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs # Python 3
except:
    from urlparse import parse_qs # Python 2.7

d = parse_qs(query_string)
d['my_param'][0]
```

Comment: Why would you parse the whole query if you only need a single value?

Comment: It has the added value of validating it is correctly formatted, handling funky character combinations, etc.

Suffice it to say that it is the Pythonic way.

Comment: Thanks this is even better than I was looking for! Didn't even know this library existed.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you need only *my_param=***value**

```
import re

your_stuff = re.findall(r"(?:^|[&? ])my_param=(.*?)(?:&|$)", your_source_string)
```

Keep in mind that this will find all occurrences of that, if more than one, so `your_stuff` contains an array of results. If you expect only a single result, you can use `re.search()` instead.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Comment: slight problem, this deletes the next & found in the string `re.sub(r"(?:^|[&? ])my_param=(.*?)(?:&|$)","&my_param={0}".format("newtoken"),request)`